# How am I able to create a new facebook offline event set?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need some help trying to create a facebook offline event set. So I was following this guide on the facebook developer:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/offline-conversions/v2.7

I am stuck on step 1) Creating an offline event set. I was able to set up a test facebook app, create the facebook business manager, and create an system admin user and valid token within business manager.

But, when I call the API using my business manager Id, the generated token, and some test data:

```
{
  "name": "offline test"
}
```

I got this error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "error_subcode": 1815062,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Account Permission Missing",
    "error_user_msg": "Ad account ************* does not have permission to access this endpoint",
    "fbtrace_id": "******"
    }
}
```

It seems like I don't have permissions which is really weird as the generated token was created on the Admin System User. Everything should be correct.

Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: What permissions does the user have granted the app?

Comment: @WizKid My access token has these scopes: ads_management, manage_pages.I followed the facebook offline conversion api guide in setting all this up.

Comment: @WizKid the weird thing is, my token is completely valid and was generated on a Admin System user.